# Winforms Binding to ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have a Windows Form with a ListBox.  The form has this method

```
public void SetBinding(BindingList<string> _messages)
{
  BindingList<string> toBind = new BindingList<string>( _messages );
  lbMessages.DataSource = toBind;
}
```

Elsewhere, I have a class called Manager that has this property

```
public BindingList<string> Messages { get; private set; }
```

and this line in its constructor

```
Messages = new BindingList<string>();
```

Finally, I have my startup program that instantiates the form and the manager and then calls

```
form.SetBinding(manager.Messages);
```

What else do I have to do so that a statement in Manager like this:

```
Messages.Add("blah blah blah...");
```

will cause a line to be added to and displayed immediately in the form's ListBox?

I don't at all have to do it this way.  I just want my Manager class to be able to post to the form while it is doing its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `SetBinding` method where you are making a **new** binding list, which means you aren't binding to the list in the Manager object anymore.

Try just passing the current BindingList to the datasource:

```
public void SetBinding(BindingList<string> messages)
{
  // BindingList<string> toBind = new BindingList<string>(messages);
  lbMessages.DataSource = messages;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the Messages.Add statement in Manager does not update lbMessages.DataSource; it's count never moves from 0.

Comment: @KellyCline I tried to mimic your code as close as possible, and when I pop messages on my Manager class, the ListBox automatically showed the new messages.  Make sure you are referencing the same Manager class.  Otherwise, you might have to update your post with more information.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new Winforms Project. Drop a ListBox. Excuse the design. Just wanted to show that it works what you want to achieve by using BindingSource and BindingList combo.

> Using the **BindingSource** is the key here

**Manager class**

```
public class Manager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// BindingList<T> fires ListChanged event when a new item is added to the list. 
    /// Since BindingSource hooks on to the ListChanged event of BindingList<T> it also is
    /// “aware” of these changes and so the BindingSource fires the ListChanged event. 
    /// This will cause the new row to appear instantly in the List, DataGridView or make any
    /// controls listening to the BindingSource “aware” about this change.
    /// </summary>
    public  BindingList<string> Messages { get; set; }
    private BindingSource _bs;

    private Form1 _form;

    public Manager(Form1 form)
    { 
        // note that Manager initialised with a set of 3 values
        Messages = new BindingList<string> {"2", "3", "4"};

        // initialise the bindingsource with the List - THIS IS THE KEY  
        _bs = new BindingSource {DataSource = Messages};
        _form = form;
    }

    public void UpdateList()
    {
         // pass the BindingSource and NOT the LIST
        _form.SetBinding(_bs);
    }
}
```

**Form1 class**

```
   public Form1()
    {
        mgr = new Manager(this);
        InitializeComponent();

        mgr.UpdateList();
    }

    public void SetBinding(BindingSource _messages)
    {
        lbMessages.DataSource = _messages;

        // NOTE that message is added later & will instantly appear on ListBox
        mgr.Messages.Add("I am added later");
        mgr.Messages.Add("blah, blah, blah");
    }
```

Comment: Another comment provided a fix, but I want to try this, too.  Thanks!

Comment: `the typical solutions programmer will use a class that provides data binding functionality, such as **BindingSource**, instead of directly using BindingList<T>.` Read the remarks section - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx