# Add item update listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, entity-framework-6

So I have a databound listbox bound to a list produced from my entity:

```
myListbox.Datasource = myEntity.ToList();
```

That works fine.  My question is, what is the 'correct' way to add a new element to the entity and have it reflected in my listbox?

Currently, I do this:

```
myEntity.Add(newItem);
myListbox.Datasource = myEntity.ToList();
```

Surely there is a better way than resetting the datasource each time?

Answer (score 0):

try this, DataBind() will binds a data source to the invoked server control and all its child controls.

```
myListbox.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thanks.  So it's like a 'reset bindings'?

Comment: Absolutely, just rebind contril

Comment: I'm using winforms, no such method exists.

Comment: @Yabbie please visit link, this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998701/winforms-binding-to-listbox

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
myListbox.ResetBindings();
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx